# tcpdf in codeigniter not working

Tags: javascript, php, sql-server, codeigniter, tcpdf

I use tcpdf to generate data into pdf but I got no result and no error.

**JS**

```
obj.fnExportpdf = () => {
    return app.callModel('romans/pdfTest'
    // onerror
    , function (jqXHR, status, errorMessage){
            alert ('ERROR: '+errorMessage);
            return false;
    }
    // onsuccess
    , function (response, status, jqXHR){
            return ;
    }
    // hide progressbar
    , false
    );  
}
```

**Model**

```
 function pdfTest(){
    $this->load->library("Pdf");
    $pdf = new Pdf('P', 'mm', 'A4', true, 'UTF-8', false);
    $pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
    // Add a page
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $html = "<h1>Test Page</h1>";
    $pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');
    ob_clean();
    return $pdf->Output('samplepdf.pdf','I');

}
```

but when I click pdftest it shows the result. [**click image**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBo4n.png)

Comment: How you configured Pdf library ?

Comment: <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');


require_once APPPATH."/third_party/tcpdf/tcpdf.php";

class Pdf extends TCPDF
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}

Comment: Is it working while calling directly from your browser ? , means  `localhost/yourapp/romans/pdfTest`

Comment: not in that path., i even curios why i can call it in this path instead romans/index.php/report/pdfTest

Comment: Did you get the PDF when you executed directly ( Without using JS ) ?

Answer (score 0):

*Download TCPD from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tcpdf/files/)*

*Create a new file: /application/libraries/Pdf.php:*

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/tcpdf/tcpdf.php';

class Pdf extends TCPDF
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}

/* End of file Pdf.php */
/* Location: ./application/libraries/Pdf.php */
```

To create a new PDF you would do something like this in your controller:

```
$this->load->library('Pdf');

$pdf = new Pdf('P', 'mm', 'A4', true, 'UTF-8', false);
$pdf->SetTitle('My Title');
$pdf->SetHeaderMargin(30);
$pdf->SetTopMargin(20);
$pdf->setFooterMargin(20);
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(true);
$pdf->SetAuthor('Author');
$pdf->SetDisplayMode('real', 'default');

$pdf->AddPage();

$pdf->Write(5, 'Some sample text');
$pdf->Output('My-File-Name.pdf', 'I');
```

Comment: still the same. I tried to alert response[error_message] on my JS I got undefined.